# What does /bin/rm -f <file> do in Unix?

Tags: rm

I came across a line and had no idea what it does. I have also checked Google, but still no luck.

```
$ /bin/rm -f fslvbm2a
```

There is no output on the screen.

Comment: By the way, `/bin/rm` = `rm` on the command line.

Comment: One of the unix philosophies, is don't output unless you need to: A command will output to standard output if its job is to provide information, else it will produce no output unless there is an error, in which case it will output to standard error.

Comment: Type `man rm`, because `/bin/rm` is `rm`, and `man rm` will show you the manual entry for `rm`.

Comment: There is a standardized way to process pathnames - [this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap04.html#tag_04_11) will provide background and help understand other cases...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`rm` is a utility use to remove directory entries in `*nix` system.

POSIX defined [rm](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/rm.html) as:

> NAME
>
> rm - remove directory entries

and `-f` option:

> -f
>
> Do not prompt for confirmation. Do not write diagnostic messages or
>   modify the exit status in the case of nonexistent operands. Any
>   previous occurrences of the -i option shall be ignored.

So `/bin/rm -f filename` remove file with name `filename` from your system silently.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great explanation. Could you please elaborate more on what you mean by "remove filename"? File deleted? File emptied?

Comment: @FarticlePilter: It deleted your file from system.

Comment: So pretty much, it is the same as `rm -f fslvbm2a`. The `\bin\` part really got me.

Comment: "remove directory entry of a filename" is exactly the same as deleting the file if there is no other [hardlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link) to the file.

Comment: @FarticlePilter: `/bin/rm` is absolute path of `rm` program. When you type only `rm`, the shell looked up path which defined by `PATH` variable. `PATH` variable oftens has `/bin` in it. So when you type `rm`, it's actually `/bin/rm` program. (Of course you can override this by define alias, function... but it's another story).

Comment: The script uses absolute path so that, the script behaviour is not modified my the users `PATH` variable, or aliases.